# how to change color of android button when user click and release the button

Tags: android

hello i am new developer on android and also fresh developer. i want to change the color of button when user click and reset the color when user release. please tell me how can i do that?
here is the layout file that i used as background of button `

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
  android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
  android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>
```

`

Comment: Look at my ans here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498606/using-a-background-drawable-selector-on-custom-button/18696987#18696987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use selectors  to achieve this functionality,and set them as a backgorund of your button like:

```
 <Button
    android:background:"@drawable/ button_bg"/>
```

create a button_bg.xml in your drawable folder like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> <!-- default -->
  </selector>
```

Create colors.xml file at res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="black">#000</color>
    <color name="blue">#00f</color>
    <color name="red">#f00</color>
</resources>
```

you van also use images  in place of color from your drawable folder

Comment: <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/> can i use my layout file in drawable?

Comment: no.and i already wrote all the things which is possible. giv a try using this.and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: yes it is working.... here is the example <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_buttons"/> <!-- default -->

Comment: i have less than 15 reputation :(

Comment: so what,you can accept the answer.and also upvote.whats the issue in that.

Comment: i can just accept the answer ... up vote shows error

Answer (score 3):

Make another drawable with the colors you want in pressed state. And make a drawable like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_focused="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"></item>
```

Use btn_pressed as pressed state drawable and btn_normal as normal drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set selector of button in your layout file.

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:background="@drawable/selector_xml_name"
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="126dp"
 android:text="Hello" />
```

Following is button_effect.xml file in drawable directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of selectors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_up" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_up" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_button"/>
</selector>
```